# Parse Local Datastore: I can't access ACL secured objects from the network after force closing the app? (Android)

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk, parse-platform

After a successful login I'm calling:

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
currentUser.isAuthenticated()
```

Now if I switch to another app via the home button or multitasking and return to my app the currentUser is still authenticated.

But if I force close the app and then reopen it the currentUser is not authenticated. Therefore it seems that I can't access any objects from the network which have the default Access Control List (ACL) added to them via:

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(new ParseACL(), true);
```

### Update with sample code:

```
    // Pinning
    ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
    gameScore.put("score", 1337);
    gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
    gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
    gameScore.pinInBackground("NEW_GAMESCORES", null);

    // Syncing Local Changes
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> localQueryNewScores = ParseQuery
            .getQuery("GameScore");
    localQueryNewScores.fromPin("NEW_GAMESCORES");

    localQueryNewScores.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> scores, ParseException e) {

            Log.d("score", "New scores = " + scores.size());

            for (ParseObject score : scores) {
                score.saveInBackground();
                score.unpinInBackground("NEW_GAMESCORES", null);

                score.pinInBackground("GAMESCORES", null);
            }
        }
    });

    // Syncing Network Changes
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> networkQueryScores = ParseQuery
            .getQuery("GameScore");

    // Query for new results from the network.
    networkQueryScores.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(final List<ParseObject> scores, ParseException e) {

            Log.d("score", "Network scores = " + scores.size());

            // Remove the previously cached results.
            ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground("GAMESCORES",
                    new DeleteCallback() {
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            // Cache the new results.
                            ParseObject.pinAllInBackground("GAMESCORES",
                                    scores);
                        }
                    });
        }
    });

    // Querying the Local Datastore
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> localQueryScores = ParseQuery
            .getQuery("GameScore");
    localQueryScores.fromPin("GAMESCORES");

    localQueryScores.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> scores, ParseException e) {
            Log.d("score", "Local scores = " + scores.size());
        }
    });
```

Log output just after I've ran the code several times:

```
New scores = 2
Local scores = 0
Network scores = 0

New scores = 0
Local scores = 0
Network scores = 2

New scores = 2
Local scores = 2
Network scores = 2

New scores = 1
Local scores = 2
Network scores = 4
```

Log output just after I've force closed the app:

```
New scores = 0
Local scores = 4
Network scores = 0

New scores = 2
Local scores = 0
Network scores = 0
```

As you can see at `Network scores = 0` after the force close I am unable to query any results from the network where I `// Query for new results from the network` to update the pinned objects in the Local Datastore with new results from the network. This happens even though I am constantly connected to the internet after the first login.

But as I need to sync back changes from the network to the Local Datastore I'm depending on this query.

**So how can I still query the network for objects that are stored with ACL added to the currentUser, after I force close the app?**

### Update 2

I found others with the same problem which has been reported here:
[developers.facebook.com/bugs/702967266408226](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/702967266408226)

It seems to be a bug in the new Parse Android SDK 1.5. I will update this post as soon as it's clear that my problem was related to the reported bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Parse Android Changelog**
>
> v1.5.1 — May 30, 2014
>
> Fixed various bugs with Local Datastore.

The problem was indeed a Local Datastore bug which has been fixed today with the release of the new Parse Android SDK version 1.5.1.

Comment: Coming back to this, there was another bug in the SDK in since corrected in v1.6.0. So even if you run 1.5.1 you might still encounter this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe save password to file, and if u reopen app after force close, log in with this saved password ?

Comment: The problem with that is, that to log in again the user would need an internet connection. But my app should still be working even after if it gets forced closed while beeing offline.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the username and password in a [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and log in again when the user re opens your app.

Comment: The problem with that is, that to log in again the user would need an internet connection. But my app should still be working even after if it gets forced closed while beeing offline.

Comment: What do you mean by "still be working"?. To perform actions in the background you might need to implement service. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Oh thanks, but with "working" I mean that I can query my ParseObjects in the Local Datastore. But I can't do that if the ParseUser is not authenticated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just check to see whether `getCurrentUser` is null or not instead of using `isAuthenticated`.

```
boolean isLoggedIn = ParseUser.getCurrentUser() != null;
```

[isAuthenticated](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html#isAuthenticated%28%29) states:

> Whether the ParseUser has been authenticated on this device. This will
>   be true if the ParseUser was obtained via a logIn or signUp method.
>   Only an authenticated ParseUser can be saved (with altered attributes)
>   and deleted.

`getCurrentUser` is always the user that has signed up or logged in. So if it is not null, the user is logged in. `isAuthenticated` is just to see if the user object was retrieved from a login/sign up or not. For example, if you queried for other `ParseUser` objects, they would not be authenticated.

Also notice that when you do a `logOut` on the current user, `getCurrentUser` will be null.

I also noticed that if you were **not** using the Local Datastore, `currentUser.isAuthenticated()` would always return true even when force closing the application.

It seems that when you are using the Local Datastore, where the current user is retrieved locally, the object is no longer seen as "authenticated" as in the source is not from a login or sign up.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. But the problem is that with "ParseACL.setDefaultACL(new ParseACL(), true);" and Local Datastore enabled I can't access/query the ParseObjects of the currentUser, which only happens when the currentUser is not authenticated after I force close the app (or reboot the phone).

Comment: @sdeff Works okay for me in that case. I set default ACL like you did, pinned an object to local datasource, force closed the app and started it up and I was able to query them from the local datasource. Do you get an error or you just get no results? You're probably doing this but make sure you're parse query calls `fromLocalDatastore` before querying.

Comment: My parse query calls `fromLocalDatastore`. Everything is working fine, even with airplane mode enabled on my phone. Just after I force close I will get no results (but no errors). It's good to know it should be working, thank you very much for testing! I'll recheck my code to see if I did anything wrong.

Comment: Could you please check the code I've added to the question. The problem happens where I Query for new results from the network to update the pinned objects in the Local Datastore with new results from the network. But I still have no solution for that :-(

Comment: @sdeff Yeah, I'll take a look when I get the chance. Hopefully someone else can solve it or yourself in the meantime. Been busy lately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just found others with the same problem which has been reported here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/702967266408226 It seems to be a bug in the new Parse Android SDK 1.5